# The input spec uses Vega-Lite v4.8.1, but the current version of Vega-Lite is v5.7.0

Tags: vega-lite, vega

Good day!

I have been getting this warning for a while and have not found a way to get rid of it. The warning reads:

```
The input spec uses Vega-Lite v4.8.1, but the current version of Vega-Lite is v5.7.0.
```

I have a React app where I use `vega` and `react-vega`. I do not use `vega-lite`. I have used `vega-lite` in the past in this same app, but I had to get rid of it since it was no longer being supported. How do I get rid of this warning in my console?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you post your spec that you're using?

Comment: @DavidBacci, how do I check the spec? I have uninstalled `vega-lite` and `react-vega-lite` packages

Comment: @DavidBacci I only have these in the npm list:
├──react-vega@7.6.0
├── vega-embed@6.21.3
├── vega-lib@4.4.0
├── vega@5.24.0

Comment: Apologies - I thought this was an issue with a spec rather than something to do with NPM. I'm not familiar with it so hopefully someone else can help.